# Hero section not showing behind transparent header

Tags: wordpress, blogs, elementor

Working on a simple blog website, I'm using astra and elementor free version of both of them, on the pages i manually added hero section image isn't showing behind the transparent header and if Change the theme them I get at least one or two elements which are not editable by elementor like they have some sort of slider menu or some of them doesn't show footer , I'm stuck with this issue for quite a few days now so any kind of assistant will be appreciated